# Cogs command message sending twice

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I switched to cogs yesterday so my code looks cleaner. Since then, all commands have broken. If you send t!profile it will send the message twice. I figured out that the problem has something to with the filter that I created.
[image]

```
        if getImmunityValue == 0:
            for word in getWord:
                if getMutedValue == 0:
                    message.content = message.content.lower()
                    if message.content.count(''.join(word)) > 0:
                        id = message.author.id
                        curs.execute('SELECT channelID FROM getchannel')
                        getChannelID = curs.fetchone()[0]

                        channel = self.client.get_channel(getChannelID)

                        curs.execute('SELECT strike FROM user WHERE userID = (%s)', (id,))
                        getstrike = curs.fetchone()[0]

                        curs.execute(f'UPDATE user SET strike = {getstrike + 1} WHERE userID = {id}')
                        db.commit()

                        await message.delete()
                        await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.mention} Bitte benutzte kein Schimpfwoerter. Falls du weiter machen solltest, wirst du gebannt oder gemutet!')

                        Embed = discord.Embed(
                            title=f'{getstrike}x strike(s) from {message.author}',
                            color=discord.Colour.red(),
                            timestamp=self.datetime.utcnow()
                        )

                        Embed.add_field(name='Blacklist Wort:', value=message.content, inline=False)
                        Embed.add_field(name='Channel-ID:', value=message.channel.id, inline=False)
                        Embed.add_field(name='Channel:', value=message.channel, inline=False)

                        await channel.send(embed=Embed)

        await self.client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: You're creating commands in `on_message` events? You should be using the [`commands`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html?highlight=commands) framework from discord.py, it will be a lot simpler :)

Comment: Na, I dont. The code you seeing is all in message event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is the `await self.client.process_commands(message)` I don't know why, but that fixes it.

Comment: It would be that in this case `self.client.process_commands(message)` would cause commands to run twice